# Lenovo T400, Ubuntu 14 wireless hardware not working consistantly

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T400. My hardware indicator switch goes off and I am unable to connect to wireless. The network manager tool will not even display a wireless interface.

This is my wireless info when it works: [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16937485/)

Comment: You might want to [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/781133/edit) your question and add a second [`pastebinit`](http://paste.ubuntu.com) link for when it not works.